# How to create several .csv files from several hashMap in Java?

Tags: java, csv, collections, hashmap

I try to create (write with data) several files from several hashMap.

```
    Map<String, List<CSVRecord>> map = new HashMap<>();

        List<CsvStructureEntity> listWithData = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                    .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                    .withTrim());

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {

                LOGGER.info("The parser read line ...");
                // Accessing values by Header names

                String line1 = csvRecord.get("line1");

                String line2 = csvRecord.get("line2");

                String lineId = csvRecord.get("lineId");

                List<CSVRecord> list = map.getOrDefault(lineId, new LinkedList<CSVRecord>());
                list.add(csvRecord);
                map.put(lineId, list);


            // Write map to new .csv files
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("/home/tmp/new_csv_file.csv")) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<CSVRecord>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    writer.append(entry.getKey())
                            .append(',')
                            .append(entry.getValue())
                            .append(lineSeparator);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }



                String line3 = csvRecord.get("line3");

                String line4 = csvRecord.get("line4");

                String line5 = csvRecord.get("line5");
... (and so on until the 43rd line)
```

My source file contains 4 different "lineId" (1,2,3,4)
Based on what I wrote, everything is written to one file. I need to write it all into different files (in different 4 files), i.e. the first file will be written lineId = 1 and all the lines for this lineId, the second file will be followed by lineId = 2 and all the lines for this lineId and so on.

Can someone say what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you expect us to tell you here? If your input data needs to go to different output files, then *you* simply have to write code that A) checks the input and then B) dispatches it to the appropriate target. What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: @GhostCat My problem here is that the data is written to one file, but I need the data to be written to different files. I can not understand why the data is written to one file.

Comment: The code you are showing ... shows how you write to one specific file?! What else do you expect then? --> Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new FileWriter for every file in which you want to write. Because currently you are creating only 1 file.